# HTTP 419 error on multiple pages after upgrade backpack to v6

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-backpack

Upgraded a backpack based internal website from v5 to v6 following the upgrade instructions here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade-guide

Upgrade went fairly smooth, I thought....

However, it seems like on every CRUD I try, I get an error 419 thrown back at me on the search URL

Also: the paths of the theme files like coreuiv2.css & common.js have the full on disk path in the URL, nothing relative

Obvious stuff like APP_URL is set correctly.

What did I miss?

`./artisan backpack:version` gives:

```
### PHP VERSION:
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2023 07:09:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

### LARAVEL VERSION:
10.16.1.0

### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:
backpack/basset: 1.0.2
backpack/crud: 6.1.0
backpack/generators: v4.0.2
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.0.0
backpack/pro: 2.0.9
backpack/settings: 3.1.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.1.4
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.0.6
```

tried validating CSRF setup, could not find any weird things

Expectation was that the CRUDs would work.

Comment: check if the key is missing in the .env file. if so, regenerate it with php artisan generate key

Comment: Thanks; the key was already there. It is an upgrade from v5 to v6 backpack. Regular pages without any backpack crud work fine, only the search returns 419 it seems (can't test any further yet)

Comment: if its only one thing that is not working then it must be missing the csrrf token in its form. You also should put this important detail in your question so [edit] it plz

Comment: Found it; permission incorrect for the webserver on the test env (storage directory)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because `common.js` is not being loaded. You can check that in developer console.

Please make sure `APP_URL` is correctly set, and that the symlink to public folder had been created: `php artisan storage:link`.

Empty all the caches: `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`.

Let me know.

Cheers

Comment: If nothing works, please share with me the configuration of your `public` disk in `config/filesystems.php`